Cannot find module 'expo/config'
I can`t test my application that I want to create by React Native.
I am trying to run the command 'expo start --web', but that shows this error:
Cannot find module 'expo/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\paths.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\validate.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Webpack.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
Error: Cannot find module 'expo/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\paths.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\validate.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\env\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\Webpack.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\internal.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\xdl\build\index.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\build\exp.js
- C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rodion\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.1\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\webpack-config\src\env\paths.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)


https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/22663

It should be @expo/config
